# Ожидание выполнения потока Winapi

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите, почему выполняется только первый поток? Как можно исправить, что бы выполнялись потоки по очереди?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct ARGS {
    int a;
    int b;
};

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunctionOne(LPVOID pArgs_)
{
    ARGS *pArgs = (ARGS*)pArgs_;

    int s = 0;
    while (pArgs->a <= pArgs->b) s += pArgs->b--;
    cout << "Сумма равна = " << s << endl;
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunctionTwo(LPVOID pArgs_)
{
    ARGS *pArgs = (ARGS*)pArgs_;
    int p = 1;
    while (pArgs->a <= pArgs->b) p *= pArgs->b--;
    cout << "Произведение равно = " << p << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int a, b;
    cout << "Введите нижнюю границу диапазона L: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Введите верхнюю границу диапазона U: ";
    cin >> b;
    ARGS args = { a, b };

    DWORD idThread;
    HANDLE h1, h2;
    // Создается два потока в приостановленном состоянии
    h1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunctionOne, &args, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &idThread);
    h2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunctionTwo, &args, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &idThread);
    ResumeThread(h1);
    WaitForSingleObject(h1, 1000);
    ResumeThread(h2);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: как я понял, тут наверное проблема в передаче аргументов, видимо нельзя передавать одни и те же аргументы функциям потоков.

Comment: В чем выражается то, что выполняется только 1 поток?

Comment: Я не помню какой конкретно, но точно решался только один поток, толи из за того, что нельзя одни и теже аргументы передавать или из за того, что они выполняются в один момент времени, либо то и другое

Comment: ваш пример корректно работает на MSVC2015. Ничего криминального в нем нет. Вы создаете два потока в приостановленном состоянии, запускаете 1-й на выполнение, ждете пока он выполниться, потом запускаете второй. До тех пор, пока потоки работают именно так, они могут использовать общие данные (args) и проблем не будет. (ну кроме разве что ошибок в логике работы). Как только вы решите запускать оба потока параллельно, возникнет гонка данных, т. е. оба потока будут пытаться модифицировать одни и те же данные, что чревато для неатомарных типов.

Comment: @goldstar_labs, только что проверил, этот код, как я и говорил, выполняется и выводит результат только первый поток, возможно второй тоже выполняется но выводит он единицу. https://i.imgur.com/pRhKqnk.png

Comment: ну так вы правильно формулируйте проблему) А то в шапке написано, что выполняется только один поток.

Answer (score 3):

Потоки выполняются по очереди как минимум потому, что у Вас стоит вызов `WaitForSingleObject`, который не завершится, пока не завершится поток `h1`.

Самый простой вариант решить проблему - отпустить оба потока через `ResumeThread` и вызвать `WaitForMultipleObjects` для обоих этих потоков с поднятым флагом `bWaitAll`

```
    ...
    HANDLE h[2];
    // Создается два потока в приостановленном состоянии
    h[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunctionOne, &args, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &idThread);
    h[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunctionTwo, &args, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &idThread);
    ResumeThread(h[0]);
    ResumeThread(h[1]);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, h, TRUE, 1000);
    ...
```

Comment: так дело в том, что первый поток выполняется, а второй нет, я подозреваю, что они просто выполняются в один момент времени? Немного не понимаю, что мне даст `WaitForMultipleObjects` ?

Comment: В данном случае `WaitForMultipleObjects` делает то же самое, что и `WaitForSingleObject` - ждет, только ждет сразу несколько потоков. Потоки не будут выполняться, пока их не отпустить через `ResumeThread`. Но у Вас тут помимо проблемы с очередностью выполнения потоков есть проблема с синхронизацией: оба потока меняют одну и ту же переменную `ARGS::b`, поэтому при параллельной их работе результат будет неверный. Судя по задаче, они вообще не должны менять общие переменные, заведите локальную в каждом потоке, скопируйте в нее `ARGS::b`, тогда получите ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 0):

Суть проблемы в некорректном выполнении расчетов второго потока, а не в том, что второй поток не выполняется. Поехали.
Для выполнения расчетов вы предоставляете потокам указатель на одни и те же данные:

```
ARGS args = { a, b };
...
h1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunctionOne, &args, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &idThread);
h2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunctionTwo, &args, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &idThread);
...
```

И первый поток эти данные успешно модифицирует

```
while (pArgs->a <= pArgs->b) s += pArgs->b--;
```

В итоге второй поток получает уже модифицированные данные и расчет производится некорректно, простым решением является создать внутри каждого потока копию входных данных, чтобы не модифицировать оригинал:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunctionOne(LPVOID pArgs_)
{
    ARGS vArgs = *(ARGS*)pArgs_;

    int s = 0;
    while (vArgs.a <= vArgs.b) s += vArgs.b--;
    cout << "Сумма равна = " << s << endl;
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunctionTwo(LPVOID pArgs_)
{
    ARGS vArgs = *(ARGS*)pArgs_;
    int p = 1;
    while (vArgs.a <= vArgs.b) p *= vArgs.b--;
    cout << "Произведение равно = " << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Либо же можно заранее каждому потоку выдать собственную копию данных (в случае, если вам важен результат модификации данных потоками)

```
ARGS argsOne = { a, b };
ARGS argsTwo = { a, b };
...
h1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunctionOne, &argsOne, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &idThread);
h2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunctionTwo, &argsTwo, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &idThread);
...
```